# Extend Entity with custom method to filter relations in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a way to extend my `Symfony2` (i currently use 2.3) `Entity` class with a method to effectively filter its relations on demand. So, imaging i have such 2 classes with `OneToMany` relation:

```
/**
 * ME\MyBundle\Entity\Kindergarten
 */
class Kindergarten
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ME\MyBundle\Entity\Kinder
     */
    private $kinders;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->kinders = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get kinders
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getKinders()
    {
        return $this->kinders;
    }
}

/**
 * ME\MyBundle\Entity\Kinder
 */
class Kinder
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $age
     */
    private $age;
}
```

**My goal** is to have a method on `Kindergarten` class to get on demand all kinders with age, for instance, between 10 and 12:

```php
   $myKindergarten->getKindersByAgeInInterval(10,12);
```

Of course, i can do something like:

```php
class Kindergarten
{
   ...

   public function getKindersByAgeInInterval($start, $end)
   {
        return $this->getKinders()->filter(
            function($kinder) use ($start, $end)
            {
                $kinderAge = $kinder->getAge();
                if($kinderAge < $start || $kinderAge > $end)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        );
   }

   ...
}
```

The solution above will work, but it's very inefficient, since I need to iterate across ALL kinders which can be a really big list and have no way to cache such filters. I have in mind usage of `Criteria` class or some proxy patterns, but not sure about a way to do it nice in `Symfony2` especially since they probably will need access to `EntityManager`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest extracting this responsibility into an `EntityRepository`:

```
<?php
class KinderRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function findByKindergartenAndAge(Kindergarten $entity, $minAge = 10, $maxAge = 20)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->... // your query logic here
    }

}
```

All the lookups should really happen in classes where you have access to the entity manager.

This is actually the way suggested by the Doctrine architecture. You can never have access to any services from your entities, and if you ever think you need it, well, then something is wrong with your architecture.

Of course, it may occur to you that the repository method could become pretty ugly if you later decide on adding more criteria (imagine you'll be searching by kindergarten, age, weight and height too, see http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html). Then you should consider implementing more logic, but again, that should not be that necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How i can use such `EntityRepository` logic, for instance, from a templates where i have `Kindergarten` entity and want to iterate from result of `findByKindergartenAndAge`?

Comment: @gakhov, well, in this case you should have the related and filtered model collection passed into your template. You should do the filtering in your controller, and there would be no need to mix concerns and put logic into your template.